# TransactionScope and rolling back object state

Tags: collections, state, transactionscope

I'm looking for a solution to a design problem.  This will take a bit of explaining.  I would post code, but that woul make this even longer.

I have a custom generic collection I use to hold Business Objects as needed.  For easy of reference, call the business objects **BO** and the generic collection **GC**.  Inside GC I have a private collection of those business objects that have been flagged for deletion. Call this private collection **PDC**.

I can have an arbitrary number of GC's, each with their own PDC, at any one time, plus other BOs that aren't in any collection.

When I save changes I loop over all BO and GC and have each one save their changes.  This happens wrapped in a TransactionScope so I rollback database changes if anything fails to save properly.

When a GC saves I have a problem with the state of its PDC.  The GC first saves all BOs with updates, then deletes records associated with the BOs in the PDC, then **clears the PDC of all BOs**.  I do this so the state of the GC correctly reflects the new state of the database.

Now suppose a BO or GC fails to save after one or more of the GC has successsfully saved .  The TransactionScope performs a rollback.  The records deleted from the database are restored, **but the some/all of the PDC's have been cleared and that state information lost**.

So here is my quandry: How do I keep the PDC information around until after the commit has occured, then guarantee the appriopriate collections are cleared?

TransactionScope has no event I can catch to let me know when it the changes have been committed.  There are potentially MANY BOs and GC affected by any given transaction, so I can't restrict the transaction to handle one GC at a time.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TransactionStarted is raised by the transaction manager, and the TransactionCompleted by the transaction itself.

You may want the GC to implement [IEnlistmentNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.ienlistmentnotification.aspx); there is an example that may help you.

You may also want to check [DNR TV show 113](http://www.dnrtv.com/default.aspx?showNum=113) and [114](http://www.dnrtv.com/default.aspx?showNum=114).

Comment: This looks perfect.  Thanks for the links as well.  This should solve my problem